# How do I detach a repository from a project in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket

Once I moved a repo under a project but I can not move it out now. The repository settings requires to select a project now. I have provided two screenshot one that is associated with a project and another with no project.

Is there any way to move a repo out of a project?

### Screenshot of Repo without a project

[image]

### Screenshot of Repo with a project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into the repository itself and change the project listed in settings.